# Problems properly configuring VB.NET combobox

Tags: vb.net

I need to put a combobox on a form that displays a list of customers.

Each customer has a customer number and customer name.

I figured out that VB.NET doesn't have multi-column combo boxes so to get around that I was going to query the data and put a tab between the customer number and name for the display members and have the value member be the customer number:

```
SELECT CustomerNumber AS ValueMember,
CustomerNumber + CHAR(9) + CustomerName AS DisplayMember
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustomerNumber
```

This only works partially in that in the selected area of the combobox, the tab between the number and name shows but when you drop-down the combobox, the tab is not preserved.

Why there is no multi-column combobox native to VB.NET annoys me but that's whole other topic.

Does anyone have any ideas for a solution to this problem that doesn't involve getting a third-party control?

Thanks.

Comment: Plenty of options, google +"multi column" +combobox

Comment: So it's basically third party or nothing for a solution then?

Answer (score 1):

If the drop down doesn't support the tab character, just replace your tab character with white space. e.g.

```
SELECT CustomerNumber AS ValueMember, 
CustomerNumber + '   ' + CustomerName AS DisplayMember 
FROM Customers 
ORDER BY CustomerNumber
```

Am I missing something?  Are you using the tab character for anything else besides formatting the displayed data?  Otherwise, 4 white spaces should achieve the same effect.

Comment: Well, I would like the two items to be evenly spaced so it looks clean in the drop down.  I guess I could calculate a set number of spaces based on the length of the customer number but there has to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: And the above of calculating spaces will only work with a fixed width font.